# How do I make a chess engine make moves in Arena?

Tags: engines, stockfish, arena

I've been trying to use Arena to analyze a position, but the engine is not making any moves. I'm using Stockfish, and I click "analyze" to let the engine do the work, however there are no results on the board. What should I do to make it move pawns?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, in particular to anyone who doesn't use Arena. Can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

In Arena 3.0, the "analyze" button does not make moves, it just tells the engine to analyze. (it should present you the analysis in the GUI itself).  if you press the "edit" button the engine will responde to your move.  the third relevant button is the "demo": it will tell the engine to play both sides until the end of the game.